# Как сделать индикатор прогресса терминала, используя python?

Tags: python, циклы, while

Я пытался сделать это через .replace(), цикл сделал на абум

```
import time
slashS = "/"
refresh1 = slashS.replace("/", "-")
refresh2 = refresh1.replace(refresh1, "\\")
refresh3 = refresh2.replace(refresh2, slashS)

while True:
    
       print(refresh3, end="") 
       time.sleep(1)
```

это код должен писать "/" потом удалять, (**но незаметно**) писать "-", снова удалять, писать "\" и так по кругу.

Но программа которую я написал это всё делает, но "в уме", поэтому она выводит просто "/", а ещё она не остается на том же месте, а переходит на следующее место для символа.

при быстром стирании и печатании, это должно быть похоже на кружок

Comment: Если это не учебный проект, используйте готовый модуль, например, [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm), а не свой велосипед.

Comment: Вы явно не понимаете, что делаете. вам вообще не нужны replace, вам нужно в консоли печатать команду забоя последнего символа и вводить очередной

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то попробуйте так, только придумайте, как выходить из цикла:

```
while True:
    print(f'\r/', end='')
    print(f'\r-', end='')
    print(f'\r\\', end='')
```

Или так:

```
import sys

while True:
    sys.stdout.write("/" * 1)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.write("\b")

    sys.stdout.write("-" * 1)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.write("\b")

    sys.stdout.write("\\" * 1)
    sys.stdout.flush(
    sys.stdout.write("\b")
```

Что больше нравится. Только в PyCharm вы полноценного вращения не увидите. Запускайте в терминале или командной строке.

Answer (score 3):

метод replace вам тут никак не поможет. алгоритм такой - выводите первый символ, ждете, выводите символ backspace (забой предыдущего символа), выводите следующий.

Ниже код для 100 циклов, если хотите, можете сделать его бесконечным:

**UPDATE**: справедливое дополнение от @CrazyElf - включить параметр flush

```
import time
from itertools import cycle
syms = ["/", "-", "\\"]
c = cycle(syms)

x = 0
while x < 100:    
    print(next(c), end="", flush=True) 
    time.sleep(.1)
    print("\b", end="") 
    x+=1
```

Comment: Хорошо бы ещё добавить `flush=True` в `print` (главным образом в первый из них), чтобы вывод не буферизовался, а то вывод может с пропусками показываться и как бы "подвисать". И возможно лучше сделать один `print` с `\r` в начале, вместо двух.